# Equivalent ruby code to following without attr_accessor?

Tags: ruby, variables, comparison, instance

This is a Java Code :

```
public class test{
     public static void main(String args[]){
     number A = new number();
     System.out.println(A.b);       
    }   
}

class number{
    int b = 100;    
}
```

Is there a equivalent of above code in ruby without attr_accessor ?

Why can't we access member variables using '.' like in java ? or is there a way i am unaware of in ruby ... ?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Transliterating from one language to another rarely works well. If you just want a bag of data, use a Hash and say `pancakes[:where]`; otherwise, use `attr_accessor` because that's how it is done in Ruby and writing Ruby in Ruby makes more sense than writing Java in Ruby.

Comment: it is just a matter of choice and context, whether Java makes more sense or ruby. It is up-to an individual as to what makes sense, instead of being so hung ho on ruby bandwagon i was just trying to see how things are done in ruby and more importantly why? They are done the way they are. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to pass around structured data, then you can use the Ruby `Struct` class, which will work more like you'd expect from your example:

```
Number = Struct.new(:value)
n = Number.new
n.value = 123
n.value # => 123
```

Answer (score 5):

Instance variables are hidden by default. You can get around this by using instance_variable_get and instance_variable_set, but these are private (you can get around this too if you must) because it's unidiomatic to do such things.

In Ruby, when you say `foo.bar`, you are invoking the `bar` method on your `foo` object (with no arguments). When you say `foo.bar = 5`, you are invoking the `bar=` method with argument `5`.

All `attr_accessor` does is provide implementations of `bar` and `bar=` for you, but this:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :bar
end
```

is equivalent to

```
class MyClass
  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def bar=(new_bar)
    @bar = new_bar
  end
end
```

This lets you later replace the implementation with something else if you wish. Instance variables are supposed to be private to that object, so I wouldn't recommend trying to work around this unless you're doing heavy-duty metaprogramming.

Comment: I understand that ruby is different and and there are different ways of doing things in ruby, my approach was to understand whether it is a feature or a bug does it have any obvious advantage over traditional approach or is it just another of those quirks in ruby. I mean is it a design issue or a feature that i dont have enough understanding of now initially while learning ?

Comment: It's just a design decision when Ruby was created. It imposes some limitations, but the creators of Ruby feel that this design decision is a useful one: because it forces you to use accessors, you're less likely to write code that directly accesses an instance variable and then later realize you need to run some functionality in that case.

Comment: Instance variable is supposed to be private ? but at the same time  Data Encapsulation from OOP school of programming describes how implementation for access of data should also be hidden. Accessor in a certain way expose the implementation. It exposes more of the interface.

Comment: Yes, instance variables are more or less private. The accessors expose an interface (the methods `bar` and `bar=`), which is equivalent to defining `getBar` and `setBar` in Java, with the obvious implementation. But it's still sufficiently abstracted that you could remove the `attr_accessor` line and provide your own accessor functions, without modifying any code that used your class.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent *is* using Ruby's `attr_accessor`. Why do you want to avoid it?

```
class number
  attr_accessor :b
end
```

Then you can call

```
a = number.new
a.b = 1
```